# How to do math expresion in queryBilder->addSelect()

Tags: symfony, orm, query-builder, dql

I need to make division of some numbers, my DQL:

```
$q
    ->addSelect("({$subDQL->getDQL()})")
    ->addSelect("calculated_sum/e.total AS available")
```

First `addSelect` return `calculated_sum` correctly but second `addSelect` throw error.

```
for:
->addSelect("calculated_sum/i.total AS available")
->addSelect($q->expr()->quot("billing_paid", "pd.total") ." AS available")

error is:
Expected Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\Lexer::T_FROM, got '/'
```

```
for:
->addSelect("QUOT(billing_paid, pd.total) AS available")

error is:
Expected known function, got 'QUOT'
```

`available` is value that going from 0 to 1 when 1 is fully available and less than 1 is partially available and 0 not available.

Comment: Are you sure the error is not in `->addSelect("calculated_sum/i.total AS available")` as it is the only place where you use `/`. If thats ok try changing `->addSelect($q->expr()->quot("billing_paid", "pd.total") ."AS available")` to `->addSelect($q->expr()->quot("billing_paid", "pd.total") ." AS available")`, maybe that single space is causing the query to fail.

Comment: @alexcm tnx, but that error was on copy to here, but my error was o using wrong logic, calculated_sum is necesary to define in main query and not in subquery and other that not posible to use variable from 1 addSelect in other, throw error in MySql.

Answer (score 0):

Dont trow error in `php` but trow in `MySql`, because `calculated_sum` is not defined when called in second select:

```
$q
    ->addSelect("({$subDQL->getDQL()}) AS HIDDEN calculated_sum")
    ->addSelect("(calculated_sum/e.total) AS HIDDEN available")
```

Correct:

```
$subDQL_cs = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('SUM(p.price)')...

$subDQL_a = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('SUM(p.price)/e.total')...

$q
    ->addSelect("({$subDQL_cs->getDQL()}) AS HIDDEN calculated_sum")
    ->addSelect("({$subDQL_a->getDQL()}) AS HIDDEN available")
```

### Note

that break `getSingleScalarResult()` it necessary to use `getSingleResult()[1]`